# Logical conditions

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints, big-m, indicator-constraints

This is similar to question I asked here: [Priotization rules for variable allocation in linear programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/priotization-rules-for-variable-allocation-in-linear-programming). In an optimization problem, the goal is to manage the purchase and sale of items under specific conditions. We have the following rules:

1. **Purchasing New Items**:

   - If the net value, calculated as $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} $, is positive, then new items should be purchased at price $CO_{t}$. This purchase is adjusted so that the net value after purchase becomes zero, formulated as $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} - CO_{t} \cdot y_{t} = 0$.
2. **Selling Items**:

   - If the net value is negative, there are two steps for selling items:

     - First, try selling new items at price $SN_{t}$ to balance the net value, formulated as $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} + SN_{t} \cdot zn_{t} = 0$.
     - If selling new items doesn't balance it, then sell initial items at price $S_{t}$ to achieve $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} + S_{t} \cdot z_{t} = 0$.
3. **Mutual Exclusivity of Transactions**:

   - At any given time $t$, only one type of transaction can occur – either buying new items, selling new items, or selling initial items. This means only one of the variables $y_{t}$, $z_{t}$, and $zn_{t}$ can be greater than zero at any time $t$.

The decision variables are defined as follows:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& x && : \text{Represents initial allocation of items}, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1. \\
& z_{t} && : \text{Represents percentage of initial items sold in year } t, \quad 0 \leq z_{t} \leq 1. \\
& y_{t} && : \text{Represents percentage of the new items purchased at time \( t \), \( 0 \leq y_t \leq 1 \)} \\
& zn_{t} && : \text{Represents percentage of new items sold at time \( t \), \( 0 \leq zn_{t} \leq 1 \)} 
\end{alignat*}

How can we formulate these conditions or prioritization rules in the optimization model? Additionally, is it possible to set a different prioritization rule where selling initial items $z_{t} > 0$ is only allowed if the selling of new items $zn_{t}$ has reached its upper bound (i.e., $zn_{t} = 1$), and purchasing new items $y_{t}$ is not permitted if either $z_{t}$ or $zn_{t}$ is positive?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. In your first bullet, what do you mean by `purchased at price CO_t`? Is $(C_t x − E_t \geq 0) \implies (y_t \geq 0)$ what you are looking for? Why have you tried to use the cost in the constraints as it really makes sense to be in the objective function?

Comment: Thanks @A.Omidi. $CO_{t}$ is the data representing cost or price you would pay for an item at time $t$- it is a vector. When $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} \geq 0$ that means we have some surplus that we use to buy new items. When you pay the cost $CO_{t} \cdot y$, you lose that amount from the account so that's why you need to factor it into the constraint. Yes, $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} \geq 0 \Rightarrow y_{t} \geq 0$ does mean a purchase at time $t$ and $C_{t} \cdot x - E_{t} - CO_{t} \cdot y = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to drop the subscript $t$ to save clutter. Let $B = C\cdot x - E.$ Introduce three binary variables $\omega_1,$ $\omega_2,$ $\omega_3$ together with the constraints $y \le \omega_1,$ $zn \le \omega_2,$ $z \le \omega_3$ and $\omega_1 + \omega_2 + \omega_3 = 1.$

We want to enforce is the following: $$\omega_1 = 1 \iff B \ge 0,$$ $$\omega_2 = 1 \iff 0 > B \ge -SN,$$ and $$\omega_3 = 1\iff -SN > B \ge -S.$$  Since exactly one $\omega_i$ will be 1 and the right hand sides form a disjoint partition of the feasible values of $B,$ it suffices to enforce just the $\implies$ direction.

Strict inequalities are taboo in LP/IP models, so read $>$ as $\ge$ in the above. The good news is that if $B = 0$ we don't care whether $y,$ $zn$ or $z$ is used since any of them would take the value 0. The remaining weakness is that if $B=-SN,$ either $\omega_2 = 1$ or $\omega_3 = 1$ would be feasible, meaning either $zn$ or $z$ could be used. If that is a problem, your only recourse is to change the third inequality to $-SN - \epsilon \ge B \ge -S$ for some small positive $\epsilon,$ the effect of which is to make any $x$ for which $-SN - \epsilon < B < -SN$ infeasible.

Finally, we add the following inequalities, where $M$ is an valid upper bound on $B:$ $$B \ge -SN\cdot \omega_2 - S\cdot \omega_3$$ and $$B \le M\cdot \omega_1 -SN\cdot \omega_3.$$ These enforce the $\implies$ directions of the three main inequalities.

Comment: Thank you. For the issue you have mentioned if $B=-SN,$ to enforce the inequality $-SN - \epsilon \ge B \ge -S$, should I change the last constraint to the following and that is the only change required? $$B \le M\cdot \omega_1 -(SN+\epsilon) \cdot \omega_3.$$

Comment: Can we apply this logic to this other similar question I have asked here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/priotization-rules-for-variable-allocation-in-linear-programming I will draft an answer building on your solution here, but happy for you to post it if you prefer it and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, this should apply. Feel free to answer the other question yourself (and maybe point to this one).

Comment: Thank you. One last thing I wanted to check was the constraint: $$\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{3} =1$$. If I change it $$\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}+\omega_{3} \leq 1$$, would that invalidate any other constraints? The reason I am considering changing it is because it may better capture the case of $$B=0$$, so that we we don't strictly enforce one of the binary variables to take value of 1.

Comment: That should be compatible with the rest of the model.